# CFNetworkHandler on iOS 9 Not Working

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cfnetwork

I am using `HttpClient` with `CFNetworkHandler`.

On iOS 9.0 I always get an empty response back:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new CFNetworkHandler());
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
var response = await client.SendAsync (request, token);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode ();
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
```

It works in older iOS versions.

If I create the `HttpClient` with the default c'tor `new HttpClient()` it works but then it doesn't use `CFNetworkHandler`.

**Update**
I switched to using `ModernHttpClient` and it works on iOS 9.0. So I assume the problem is in `CFNetworkHandler`.

Comment: I have the same problem too, if you investigate further `httpResponseMessage.Content` has a header with `Content-Length: 892` so obviously the data is there but ... something isn't working.

Comment: Agree, I experience exactly the same behavior - content length is correct but the content is empty.